# Adding a UIPanGestureRecognizer to UITableViewCell causes odd behaviour in iPhone X Landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

I have some code in my HW Cell as seen below. I am leaving out the extra code that appears to be largely unrelated.

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HWCell.handlePan(_:)))
        self.recognizer.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(self.recognizer)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.cardView.layoutIfNeeded() //Needed for iOS10 since layoutSubviews() reports inaccurate frame sizes.
        self.cardView.layer.cornerRadius = self.cardView.frame.size.height / 3
        self.cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }

    //MARK: - horizontal pan gesture methods

    func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // 1
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
            originalCenter = self.center
            //originalCenter = self.cardView.center
            self.bringSubview(toFront: self.contentView)
            self.originalAlpha = self.cardView.alpha

        }
        // 2
        if recognizer.state == .changed {
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)
            self.center = CGPoint(x: originalCenter.x + translation.x, y: originalCenter.y)

// 3 //Remembered, state == .Cancelled when recognizer manually disabled.
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            // the frame this cell had before user dragged it
            let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
                                       width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            if (!deleteOnDragRelease && !completeOnDrag) {
                // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: { self.frame = originalFrame }, completion: nil)
                if (self.task?.completed == false) {
                    UIView.transition(with: self.completionImageView,
                                              duration: 0.2,
                                              options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
                                              animations: { self.completionImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Grey Checkmark") },
                                              completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

What happens is that, and keep in mind that this ONLY HAPPENS on iPhone X in Landscape mode, is the cell extends itself further by stretching instead of simply moving when I drag my finger across it.

You can see this behaviour in a video I uploaded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPXZWwnuWhU&feature=youtu.be

This odd behaviour never occurs in iOS10, only in iOS 11, on this particular device and orientation.

My constraints are blue and 0 warnings/errors, I played around with them to see if the safe area was related to this problem. The problem is gone only if I set the leading/trailing constraints of the UITableView to line up with the Safe Area. If they are lined up with the Superview, this error occurs.

Anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: But why to do such a thing if it's already available when conforming to `UITableViewDelegate` and implementing `didSelectRow` method?

Comment: This is a custom behaviour that I am creating. Not something possible in UITableViewDelegate. Hence why I am using pan.